# How to observe property value changes of a third party object?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, observable, propertydescriptor

I would like to observe whenever a property of a third party object is changed. I'm taking the approach of assigning a custom setter but my `console.log` below is never invoked. Why is that? Is there a better approach?

```
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 };

Object.assign(foo, {
  set user(user) {
    foo.user = user;
    console.log(">>>>>> user was changed", user);
  },
});

// Desired behaviour
foo.user = "asdf"; // >>>>>> user was changed asdf
delete foo.user; // >>>>>> user was changed undefined
foo.user = "asdf1" // >>>>>> user was changed asdf1
```

Please note, I need to mutate `foo` I cannot wrap a proxy around foo and return that because it is a third party library which mutates `.user` internally

Comment: This is a good use case for a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: No I can't use proxy here as proxy doesn't modify the underlying target to my knowledge @Reyno and Pavan J

Comment: But the proxy points to the same object so changing the proxied object will also change `foo`?

Comment: Yeah fair enough @Andreas I appreciate it's been re-opened 

Comment: @Reyno If you cannot change the line `const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 };` then you cannot really use a proxy.

Comment: exactly @VLAZ - correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way, pretty hacky as it is

```js
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 };

let underlyingValue = foo.user

Object.defineProperty(foo, "user", {
  get() {
    return underlyingValue
  },
  set(user) {
    underlyingValue = user;
    console.log(">>>>>> user was changed", user);
  },
  enumerable: true
});

foo.user = "asdf";
console.log(foo)
```

I've made this into a generic function below

```js
/** Intercepts writes to any property of an object */
function observeProperty(obj, property, onChanged) {
  const oldDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, property);
  let val = obj[property];
  Object.defineProperty(obj, property, {
    get() {
      return val;
    },
    set(newVal) {
      val = newVal;
      onChanged(newVal);
    },
    enumerable: oldDescriptor?.enumerable,
    configurable: oldDescriptor?.configurable,
  });
}

// example usage 
const foo = { a: 1 };
observeProperty(foo, "a", (a) => {
  console.log("a was changed to", a);
});
foo.a = 2; // a was changed to  2
```

[Also available in typescript](https://gist.github.com/mfbx9da4/8832919b60f0be19165488e4ad7a46d0)

> Edit: This will break if the property is deleted eg `delete foo.user`. The observer will be removed and the callback will stop firing. You will need to re-attach it.

Comment: Indeed *"... pretty hacky as it is."* ... In this case `user` is not enumerable like `a` and `b`. And how about observing other properties than just `user`. Is the latter a special case or does the OP need a somehow more generic observation approach?

Comment: `foo` is not a property you might need to re-word your comment?

Comment: Good point I'll make it enumerable. As for a generic approach yeah that's in the collapsed snippet

Answer (score 1):

@david_adler ... when I commented ...

> *"Is the latter a special case or does the OP need a somehow more generic observation approach?"*

... I thought of the most generic solution one could come up with in terms of changing/mutating an existing object entirely into an observable variant of itself.

Such a solution also would be more close to what the OP did ask for ...

> *"I would like to observe whenever a property of a third party object is changed"*

Thus the next provided approach keeps the objects appearance and behavior and also does not introduce additional (e.g. `Symbol` based) keys.

```js
function mutateIntoObservableZombie(obj, handlePropertyChange) {
  const propertyMap = new Map;

  function createAccessors(keyOrSymbol, initialValue, handler) {
    return {
      set (value) {
        propertyMap.set(keyOrSymbol, value);
        handler(keyOrSymbol, value, this);
        return value;
      },
      get () {
        return propertyMap.has(keyOrSymbol)
          ? propertyMap.get(keyOrSymbol)
          : initialValue;
      },
    };
  }
  function wrapSet(keyOrSymbol, proceed, handler) {
    return function set (value) {
      handler(keyOrSymbol, value, this);
      return proceed.call(this, value);
    };
  }
  function createAndAssignObservableDescriptor([keyOrSymbol, descriptor]) {
    const { value, get, set, writable, ...descr } = descriptor;

    if (isFunction(set)) {
      descr.get = get;
      descr.set = wrapSet(keyOrSymbol, set, handlePropertyChange);
    }
    if (descriptor.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
      Object.assign(descr, createAccessors(keyOrSymbol, value, handlePropertyChange));
    }
    Object.defineProperty(obj, keyOrSymbol, descr);
  }
  const isFunction = value => (typeof value === 'function');

  if (isFunction(handlePropertyChange)) {
    const ownDescriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
    const ownDescrSymbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(ownDescriptors);

    Object
      .entries(ownDescriptors)
      .forEach(createAndAssignObservableDescriptor);

    ownDescrSymbols
      .forEach(symbol =>
        createAndAssignObservableDescriptor([symbol, ownDescriptors[symbol]])
      );
  }
  return obj;
}


// third party object (closed/inaccessible code)
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 };


// custom changes already.
foo.userName = '';
foo.userLoginName = '';

const userNick = Symbol('nickname');

foo[userNick] = null;

console.log('`foo` before descriptor change ...', { foo });

mutateIntoObservableZombie(foo, (key, value, target) => {
  console.log('property change ...', { key, value, target });
});
console.log('`foo` after descriptor change ...', { foo });

foo.a = "foo bar";
foo.b = "baz biz";

console.log('`foo` after property change ...', { foo });

foo.userName = '****';
foo.userLoginName = '************@**********';

console.log('`foo` after property change ...', { foo });

foo[userNick] = 'superuser';

console.log('`foo` after symbol property change ...', { foo });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

Since the above approach already is implemented generic and modular it of cause easily can be refactored into a function which allows the exact definition of which property/ies, both `string` and `symbol` based, are going to be observed ...

```js
function observePropertyChange(obj, keysAndSymbols, handlePropertyChange) {
  const propertyMap = new Map;

  function createAccessors(keyOrSymbol, initialValue, handler) {
    return {
      set (value) {
        propertyMap.set(keyOrSymbol, value);
        handler(keyOrSymbol, value, this);
        return value;
      },
      get () {
        return propertyMap.has(keyOrSymbol)
          ? propertyMap.get(keyOrSymbol)
          : initialValue;
      },
    };
  }
  function wrapSet(keyOrSymbol, proceed, handler) {
    return function set (value) {
      handler(keyOrSymbol, value, this);
      return proceed.call(this, value);
    };
  }
  function createAndAssignObservableDescriptor(keyOrSymbol, descriptor) {
    const { value, get, set, writable, ...descr } = descriptor;

    if (isFunction(set)) {
      descr.get = get;
      descr.set = wrapSet(keyOrSymbol, set, handlePropertyChange);
    }
    if (descriptor.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
      Object.assign(descr, createAccessors(keyOrSymbol, value, handlePropertyChange));
    }
    Object.defineProperty(obj, keyOrSymbol, descr);
  }
  const isString = value => (typeof value === 'string');
  const isSymbol = value => (typeof value === 'symbol');
  const isFunction = value => (typeof value === 'function');

  if (isFunction(handlePropertyChange)) {

    const ownDescriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
    const identifierList = (Array
      .isArray(keysAndSymbols) && keysAndSymbols || [keysAndSymbols])
      .filter(identifier => isString(identifier) || isSymbol(identifier));

    identifierList
      .forEach(keyOrSymbol =>
        createAndAssignObservableDescriptor(keyOrSymbol, ownDescriptors[keyOrSymbol])
      );
  }
  return obj;
}


// third party object (closed/inaccessible code)
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 };


// custom changes already.
foo.userName = '';
foo.userLoginName = '';

const userNick = Symbol('nickname');

foo[userNick] = null;

console.log('`foo` before descriptor change ...', { foo });

observePropertyChange(
  foo,
  ['b', 'userLoginName', userNick],
  (key, value, target) => { console.log('property change ...', { key, value, target }); },
);
console.log('`foo` after descriptor change ...', { foo });

foo.a = "foo bar";
foo.b = "baz biz";

console.log('`foo` after property change ...', { foo });

foo.userName = '****';
foo.userLoginName = '************@**********';

console.log('`foo` after property change ...', { foo });

foo[userNick] = 'superuser';

console.log('`foo` after symbol property change ...', { foo });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @david_adler ... when I commented ... *"Is the latter a special case or does the OP need a somehow more generic observation approach?"* ... I thought of the most generic solution one could come up with in terms of changing/mutating an existing object entirely into an observable variant of itself. Such a solution also would be more close to what the OP did ask for ... *"I would like to observe whenever a property of a third party object is changed"* ... Thus the above provided approach keeps the objects appearance and behavior and also does not introduce additional (e.g. `Symbol` based) keys.

Comment: yeah good approach, no need for the symbol property, have updated my implementation to be more similar to yours. However, in my particular use case, I don't need to observe all properties so I would prefer not to deal with the complexities of observing methods etc.

Comment: @david_adler ... in this case you might consider being more precise with the description and the title ( _**"Observe any property of an object"**_ ).

Comment: cool, done that now. I think you're answer may prove useful anyway for other future googlers

Comment: One issue that this doesn't solve (and nor does my above solution) is that the observability is broken if you delete the property e.g `delete foo.a; foo.a = "asdf"`

Comment: @david_adler ... Correct, one needs to make a decision. For the mutated observable object one needs to decide, either leaving its appearance/behavior as is, or whether one wants to reassign each observable property explicitly via its descriptor as `configurable: false` which would prevent deleting it.

Comment: Yeah but a better solution would be (a) inheriting configurable from original object and (b) being able to detect deletions and preserving the observer in that case. Whether or not it's possible is the question!

Comment: @david_adler ... I can't think of any alternatives. That's why I presented my last comment as final choice. From what we came up with, I think it's as far as one could go with a property descriptor based approach.

Comment: I played around with some ideas of Object.assign a Proxy onto the object and or modifying the underlying prototype but I didn't get too far. I still have faith it's possible 